# Writing persian ( farsi ) by class wfstream in output file

Tags: c++, string, unicode, persian, farsi

How can I write Persian text like "خلیج فارس" to a file using a `std::wfstream`?
I tried following code but it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::wfstream f("D:\\test.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::wstring s1(L"خلیج فارس");
    f << s1.c_str();
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The file is empty after running the program.

Comment: I checked  the output file , it is empty

Comment: `f.imbue(std::locale(""));` if farsi is your default system locale
(http://stackoverflow.com/a/2169088/1566267)

Comment: Does it have to be std::wfstream or is std::fstream allowed too?

Comment: @robsn: Yes, as it is declared in `ios_base`.

Comment: Specify your platform - Windows, Linux, Mac? On some OSes, console is Unicode friendly, on some - not so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a C++11 utf-8 string literal and standard fstream and string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f("D:\\test.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::string s1(u8"خلیج فارس");
    f << s1;
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can left

```
f << s1.c_str();
```

Just use

```
f << s1;
```

To write "خلیج فارس" with `std::wstream` you must specify `imbue` for persian locale like:

```
f.imbue(std::locale("fa_IR"));
```

before you write to file.

Comment: sorry, I think it should be `fa_IR` (http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/locale.html)

Comment: @John_West: I do not know much about eastern languages.

Comment: @John_West: Thank you for response!